# Creating new label and computing the corresponding value in existing columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new label in an existing column (e.g. column A) and to create a computed value in the same row in another existing column (e.g. column B).

A simulated data looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("31-Dec-2018", "31-Dec-2018", "31-Dec-2018", "30-Sep-2018", "30-Sep-2018", "30-Jun-2018", "30-Jun-2018",
                              "31-Mar-2018", "31-Mar-2018"), format = "%d-%b-%Y"),
             metric = c("Revenue", "Profit", "Restructuring Cost", "Revenue", "Profit", "Revenue", "Profit", "Revenue", "Profit"),
             value = c(100, 50, 10, 100, 50, 90, 44, 97, 60))
```

There are three columns (date, financial metric, and the corresponding value for that financial metric for that particular date). For example, I would like to compute the net profit margin for each date (Profit for particular date divided by revenue for that same date). However, `mutate` does it wrongly; it creates a new computed column. I want the "Net Margin" label to be created in the existing "metric" column and the corresponding net margin value in the "value" column.

What I have done thus far (which is wrong) is the following:

```
test <- df %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(net_margin = round(value/lag(value), digits = 2))
```

I am not sure of how to call for the metric as well. My above code uses the value of the previous row, but this may not be the case all the time.

The desired output would look something like the following:

[image: Example]

Thanks!

Comment: you also want to add rows for restructuring cost/Revenue ? Why all dates do not have that row?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes. There might be one-off financial metrics that might occur from time to time. I am planning to implement this on a Shiny App that users can interact with your "Standard" metrics as well as the occasional "one-off" metrics with `selectInput` as and when one-off metrics are available.

Comment: `bind_rows(df, df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(value = round(value[metric == "Profit"]/value[metric == "Revenue"], 2), 
            metric = "Net Margin")) %>%
  arrange(date)` this works to add "Net Margin" rows. I am not clear how to add the one-off metrics since they are not guaranteed to appear for every date and there could be many other metrics as well apart from "Restructuring cost".

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for your help. Do you want to post your comment as a answer so that I can close the question. No worries regarding the one-off financial metrics. When the issue crops up in the future, I'll ask another question then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `summarise` by `date` and calculate ratio of `value` at "Profit" by that at "Revenue" and bind the rows to original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(value = round(value[metric == "Profit"]/value[metric == "Revenue"], 2), 
           metric = "Net Margin") %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(date)


#    date       value metric            
#   <date>      <dbl> <chr>             
# 1 2018-03-31   0.62 Net Margin        
# 2 2018-03-31  97    Revenue           
# 3 2018-03-31  60    Profit            
# 4 2018-06-30   0.49 Net Margin        
# 5 2018-06-30  90    Revenue           
# 6 2018-06-30  44    Profit            
# 7 2018-09-30   0.5  Net Margin        
# 8 2018-09-30 100    Revenue           
# 9 2018-09-30  50    Profit            
#10 2018-12-31   0.5  Net Margin        
#11 2018-12-31 100    Revenue           
#12 2018-12-31  50    Profit            
#13 2018-12-31  10    Restructuring Cost
```

Comment: Just another question, what is the role of the metric = "Net Margin" parameter in the `summarise` function? When I checked the help page for the `summarise` function, it did not mention such a parameter.

Comment: @DTYK for each `date` we want two columns `value` and `metric`. `value` column is calculated by `value[metric == "Profit"]/value[metric == "Revenue"]` and for `metric` column we give a label as we need here it is "Net Margin". You can also use "Total" or any string of your choice. Run this chunk and it might help you understand what we are adding to original data frame. `df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(value = round(value[metric == "Profit"]/value[metric == "Revenue"], 2), 
            metric = "Net Margin")
`